# What is DM burnout?

Tags: terminology, gm-burnout

So me and a couple of my friends that have not had any experience with D&D decided to play, I volunteered to be the DM and have been wandering around reading all the rules and learning common knoledge. I have seen this term a few times, but I don't know what it means: What is DM burnout? and also, how do I deal with it

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, the “how to deal with it” part is answered there, and it should be clear enough what we mean when we say “GM burnout”. If you really want to just have a Q&A focused on defining the term, that’s probably fine, but I really think the linked question should have everything you need to know.

Comment: I’ve also added the GM-burnout tag, the tag description has a succinct definition.